# Понял как решить задачу, написал код - не работает

Tags: javascript

Всем привет!
На javascript.ru прохожу курс, не получается решить одну задачу, смотреть в ответ не хочу. Суть задачи:
дан массив с элементами в виде строк-анаграмм

```js
var arr = ["воз", "киборг", "корсет", "ЗОВ", "гробик", "костер", "сектор"];
```

Нужно написать функцию aClean, возвращающую массив слов, очищенный от анаграмм.   Ответ должен быть таким:

```
"воз,киборг,корсет" или "ЗОВ,гробик,сектор".
```

Реализовывал так:

```js
function aClean(arr) {
  var arrClone = arr.concat(); 

  for (var i = 0; i < arrClone.length; i++) {

    arrClone[i] = arrClone[i].toLowerCase();        
    var elem = arrClone[i].split('').sort();
    arrClone[i] = elem.join('');
  }
    
    for (var k = 0; k < arrClone.length; k++) {
      
      for (var j = 1; j < arrClone.length; j++) {
        if (arrClone[k] == arrClone[j]) {
          
          delete arr[j];
        }

      }
    } 
     return arr;
}  
var arr = ["воз", "киборг", "корсет", "ЗОВ", "гробик", "костер", "сектор"];
aClean(arr);
alert( arr );
```

В чем проблема?

Comment: подумай, что у тебя делает двойной for

Comment: в двойном for я сравниваю arrClone[k] с arrClone[j]. Итерация j начинается со второго элемента массива, чтобы не сравнивать каждый элемент с самим собой. Если элемент массива arrClone равен следующему элементу, удаляю следующий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка тут:

```
  for (var j = 1; j < arrClone.length; j++) {
```

заменить на:

```
  for (var j = k+1; j < arrClone.length; j++) {
```

Иначе получается, что все слова после нулевого сравниваются сами с собой в одной из итераций цикла

```js
function aClean(arr) {
  var arrClone = arr.concat(); 

  for (var i = 0; i < arrClone.length; i++) {

    arrClone[i] = arrClone[i].toLowerCase();        
    var elem = arrClone[i].split('').sort();
    arrClone[i] = elem.join('');
  }
    
    for (var k = 0; k < arrClone.length; k++) {
      
      for (var j = k+1; j < arrClone.length; j++) {
        if (arrClone[k] == arrClone[j]) {
          
          delete arr[j];
        }

      }
    } 
     return arr;
}  
var arr = ["воз", "киборг", "корсет", "ЗОВ", "гробик", "костер", "сектор"];
aClean(arr);
alert( arr );
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Я знал что найдется добрый человек и поможет советом, на javascript.ru никто не отозвался

Comment: @PavelTimofeev если хотите поблагодарить, отметьте ответ как верный -   галочка слева от него (можно и плюсик поставить)

Comment: дело сделано, сэр))